# VB: How to insert a query result into an .xlsx file via a StringBuilder

Tags: mysql, excel, vb.net, forms

I need to insert the result of the query into a .xlsx file but I can't find the method to make the StringBuilder talk to the ranges of the Excel sheet.
The instruction oSheet.Range("A1") inserts in the first cell of the sheet all the records resulting from the query.
Can anyone recommend a method to make the columns and cells resulting from the query appear as they appear in the database?

**Below is my code:**

```vb
Try
    'G7 Report
    Dim G7Dettagli As New DataSet
    G7Dettagli = DB_SQL.OpenDataset("SELECT Anagrafica.CodiceSocio AS [Code Client], Anagrafica.Denominazione AS [Denominazione Socio], EU_VACON_10.ExternalOBUID, EU_VACON_10.PanNumber, EU_VACON_10.Targa AS Immatriculation, EuroClasse.ClasseVera AS [Classe Euro], EU_VACON_10.EntryDate AS [Date et heure], EU_TOLLCharger.Sigla AS Société, EU_STCon.Motorway AS [AUT ENTREE], EU_STCon.Denominazione AS [Libellé ENTREE], EU_STCon_1.Motorway AS [AUT SORTIE], EU_STCon_1.Denominazione AS [Libellé SORTIE], EU_VACON_10.AmountExcludedDiscount AS HT, EU_VACON_10.VATRate AS [%TVA], EU_VACON_10.AmountIncludingVAT AS TTC, EU_VACON_10.ExitGateCode, EU_VACON_10.Kilometers, Nazioni.Denominazione AS Nation
FROM (((((EU_VACON_10 LEFT JOIN Anagrafica ON EU_VACON_10.ID_Cliente = Anagrafica.ID_cliente) LEFT JOIN EuroClasse ON EU_VACON_10.ID_Classe = EuroClasse.ID_Classe) LEFT JOIN EU_STCon ON EU_VACON_10.EntryGateCode = EU_STCon.GlobalGateIdentifier) LEFT JOIN EU_STCon AS EU_STCon_1 ON EU_VACON_10.ExitGateCode = EU_STCon_1.GlobalGateIdentifier) LEFT JOIN EU_TOLLCharger ON (EU_VACON_10.TSPCountryCode = EU_TOLLCharger.CountryCode) AND (EU_VACON_10.TSPNumber = EU_TOLLCharger.TspCode)) LEFT JOIN Nazioni ON EU_VACON_10.TSPCountryCode = Nazioni.ISO366
WHERE (((EU_VACON_10.ID_Cliente)=20444));", "Anagrafica.ID_cliente")
    Try

        Dim oExcel As Object
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
        oSheet.Name = "test"

        Dim DttDatiEsporta2 As DataTable = G7Dettagli.Tables(0)
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim NomiColonne As IEnumerable(Of String) = DttDatiEsporta2.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().[Select](Function(column) column.ColumnName)
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join(";", NomiColonne))
        For Each row As DataRow In DttDatiEsporta2.Rows
            Dim Elementi As IEnumerable(Of String) = row.ItemArray.[Select](Function(elemento) elemento.ToString())
            sb.AppendLine(String.Join(";", Elementi))
        Next

        oSheet.Range("A1").Value = sb.ToString
        oBook.SaveAs("G:\Fatture PER Gruppi\2021\" + DataAlContrario + "\Cosar\Cosar_G7.xlsx")
        oBook.Close()
        oBook = Nothing
        oExcel.Quit()
        oExcel = Nothing

        'Dim fileName As String = Path.Combine("G:\Fatture PER Gruppi\2021\" + DataAlContrario + "\Cosar", "Cosar_G7.xlsx")
        'File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString())

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I don't really use Excel much at all but, as far as I can tell, setting the `Value` of a `Range` will set the same value in each cell in the range. If you expect to use different values for each cell then you'd need to use a loop. You can use nested `For` loops to access the fields in your `DataRows` and the corresponding cells in Excel. You would index the `Cells` collection rather than using a `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really use Excel at all but, based on a general understanding of how these things work and about two minutes of research on Excel, I think that you'd need to something like this:

```vb
For rowIndex = 0 To DttDatiEsporta2.Rows.Count - 1
    For columnIndex = 0 To DttDatiEsporta2.Columns.Count - 1
        oSheet.Cells(columnIndex + 1, rowIndex + 1).Value = DttDatiEsporta2.Rows(rowIndex)(columnIndex)
    Next
Next
```